# Change date format in cakePHP query

Tags: sql, datetime, cakephp, conditional-statements

I have a table `room_booking_datas` in which the format of the field `checkin_time` is `datetime`. So the values of this field are `2015-01-24 05:25:01`, `2015-01-24 05:25:40` etc. Now I need to check the last checkin data for a particular date say for `2015-01-24`.

```
$date = `2015-01-24`;
$cond['RoomBookingData.checkin_time'] = $date;

$res = $this->RoomBookingData->find('first', array('conditions' => $cond, 'order' => 'RoomBookingData.checkin_time DESC'));
```

But as expected , the `$res` shows empty result ! How can I get the result for the `$date` ?

Comment: you can change the data type, datetime to date

Comment: @vikramsharma I can't change date format, its required in other functions. Just in this function I do not need the time

Comment: @Nitesh your $date='2015-01-24' is current date or not

Comment: For SQL related question please always mention the DBMS that your are using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = `2015-01-24`;

$res = $this->RoomBookingData->find(
'first', 
array(
    'conditions' => array( 
        DATE('RoomBookingData.checkin_time') => $date
    ), 
    'order' => 'RoomBookingData.checkin_time DESC'
    )
);
```

Comment: You seem to assume MySQL, in that case there's no need to explicitly use formatting, you could just use `DATE()`. Should also be a little faster.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting the hang of Cake, and I can't seem to understand why the use of `$cond['RoomBookingData.checkin_time']`. Isn't it going to point to $date anyway, since you're passing the value, and not the array? And if you do pass the $date variable, how will cake know which field to look at?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2015-01-24 00:00:00';
$date = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
$tomorrow = date('m-d-Y H:i:s',strtotime($date . "+1 days"));
```

and then...

```
$query_array = array(
    'conditions' => array('RoomBookingData.checkin_time <' => $tomorrow),
    'order' => array('RoomBookingData.checkin_time DESC'),
);
```